# redis 2.6.16 not installing on mac with no error

Tags: macos, redis

I have a mac OS X 10.8. I have installed `GCC-10.7-v2.pkg` and `Xcode 5` with its up-to-date dev tools

I download `Redis 2.6.16 (stable)` from `http://redis.io/download`

1. open terminal
2. List item
3. go to downloads folder
4. List item
5. unzip the file
6. rename the unzip folder to `redis`
7. run `make test`

it says `\o/ All tests passed without errors!`

1. run `make` or `cd src && make`

but all I get is `Hint: To run 'make test' is a good idea ;)`

What am I missing?

Comment: This message is just displayed at the end of a successful compilation. What did you expect?

Comment: After running the `make test` i need to run just `make`. and it always tell me to run the test. never compiles it.

Comment: I don't understand why you run make test before make. You are supposed to compile first, and test after.

Comment: I cant compile, everytime i try to compile I get the "Hint" message

Comment: Do you have a redis-server executable in the src directory? If yes, it means Redis is already compiled. If no, I would say there is something wrong with the version of make, and you need to adapt the makefile.

Comment: There are no redis-server executable in the src directory. How would I do what you suggest?

Comment: I would start by checking make version (make --version) and then run make with debug flags (-d) to see what happens.

Comment: I have the same problem. (Mac OS X) I should install a redis server and this message displayed every time when I type 'make'... It is annoying.